# .urdf file to .world file

Tags: ros, urdf, world

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to import my model .URDF file to .WORLD file

for empy.world :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <world name="default">
    <!-- A ground plane -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://*mymodel*</uri>
    </include>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

and for the model.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model>
  <name>test robot</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <urdf version='1.4'>model.urdf</urdf>
  <description>
     tuto
  </description>
</model>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216204/.urdf-file-to-.world-file/) by [ahmed charef](https://answers.ros.org/users/23500/ahmed-charef/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-08-20

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-08-24**:
Your question is poorly written. It is not clear what you want, and that is why you got a downvote (probably). Please elaborate it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ahmed charef! I think that you're trying to link your URDF robot model to a world and launch it in gazebo.

If is that case it's explain in gazebo tutorials [link](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_roslaunch), but i'm going to try to explain to you.

In the model.config file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <model>
    <name>MYROBOT</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <sdf>urdf/MYROBOT.urdf</sdf> <--- **Here you must specify where is your urdu file** -->
    <author>
      <name>My name</name>
      <email>name@email.address</email>
    </author>
    <description>
      A description of the model
    </description>
  </model>
```

And then, in the world file you must include it as the rest of things in the world

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<sdf version="1.4">
  <world name="default">
    <!-- Ground Plane -->
    <include>
        <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <!-- Your URDF file -->
    <include>
        <uri>model://MYROBOT</uri>  <!-- The name that you write in the model.config -->
    </include>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

I hope this can help you.

---

Originally posted by [silth](https://answers.ros.org/users/23638/silth/) with karma: 30 on 2015-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahmed charef](https://answers.ros.org/users/23500/ahmed-charef/) on 2015-08-25**:
Thank you !
i have tried that,but it doesn't work for me

**Comment by [silth](https://answers.ros.org/users/23638/silth/) on 2015-08-25**:
could you post your .launch file?

**Comment by [Anurag VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/29692/anurag-vv/) on 2017-07-25**:
Thank you! This helped. I need a clarification. I know I am new to ROS/Gazebo but why am I unable to find this direction or solution myself by going through the tutes/documentation of gazebo/ROS? Am i being dumb at reading the documentation or is it because the tutes/documentati are just bad?